# Links are not working while using css

Tags: html, css, search

I've faced a problem which I couldn't solve by Googling. I've got a static HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <input class="search" type="text" placeholder="Search..." />
    <ul class="results">
        <li><a href="google.com">Google it</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

And the css file:

```
.search:focus + .results { display: block; }

.results {
    display:none;
}
```

It shows ul element when I textBox is focused, but when I try to click on the link, it just disappears. Please explain why this happens.

Comment: your list is only visible when the `.search` element has the focus. When you click on the link, that element loses the focus, and the list item disappears before receiving the click event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a pure CSS workaround. The problem is not with the link, but with the fact that it is being hidden while unfocusing the input. So I improved your CSS selector to include `:hover` pseudo-class on the `ul` tag. Working example:

```css
.search:focus + .results, ul:hover { display: block; }

.results {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <input class="search" type="text" placeholder="Search..." />
    <ul class="results">
        <li><a href="google.com">Google it</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: Yup. I've already found that up. But I will accept it as answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

OP. I've used jQuery to show the list on click of the input box. It will make the list stay.

```
$( ".search" ).click(function() {
  $( ".results" ).show();
});
```

and changed css to

```
.results {
    display: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5hmfwdvc/

Once you un-focus the input, it'll retract the CSS making the list being shown. jQuery solves this.