# Mobile menu button 2 clicks to toggle the menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

Using: VS 2013, ASP.NET (VB) Webforms.

Upgrading WebForms web site from .NET 2.0 to .NET 4.5 and adding mobile-friendliness for Google support.

Created a button in Top right corner like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="toggleMenuDiv();">
    <img class="headerimg-r" src="/images/MenuBtn6464.png" />
</a>
```

The javascript looks like this:

```
    function toggleMenuDiv() {
    var menu = document.getElementById('menu');
    if (menu.style.display == 'none') {
        menu.style.display = 'block';
    }
    else {
        menu.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

the element with id "menu" looks like:

```
<div class="dropdownmenu" id="menu">
```

However, to drop the menu down I need to touch twice and not once. All menu links work properly without multiple touches.

Feel free to see it yourself.  Hit http://www.pedfast.com from a mobile device and give it a try.

I know I'm missing something simple; can someone point me in the correct direction?

Thanks!

Comment: You could use jQuery click and slideToggle instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the `menu.style.display` not equal to `none` at the beginning?

So, first time youre you click the menu you will set the `display` to `none`. And second time the `display` are `none` and thats the reason why it works at the second click!

I think you need to check if the `display` not equal to `block` then set it to `block`!

Try this:

```
if (menu.style.display != 'block') {
    menu.style.display = 'block';
}
else {
    menu.style.display = 'none';
}
```

**EDIT**
Just look at @Billy Purvis answer. You can also add `.toggle()` instead of `.show()` if you want to `hide` the menu again.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the div with the attribute id === "menu" have not the value `display: none;` as style attribute, so basically at the first click your code is assigning to the element that value, and then, in the second click the value `display: block`

Extracted from the linked page:

```
<div class="dropdownmenu" id="menu">
```

It should be

```
<div class="dropdownmenu" id="menu" style="display: none;">
```

Comment: The style sheet in a separate CSS file defaults to display: none;

Answer (score -1):

Here, I created a jsFiddle showing use of jQuery. It's cleaner and easier to understand and only relies on a single click. 
I couldn't recreate yours without more code, so I create an example to show the logic, it should be easy to use the logic in your example.

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $(".menu").show();
});
```

Once the button (or a tag) is clicked, it'll show the menu. Putting this css on menu hides it until it's needed

```
.menu {
    display: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yhf3dfcs/

Comment: This would work great, however, I tough that the down votes are from the fact that the OP is not asking from a different solution and in this case, it is not necessary to include an entire library like jquery to solve that problem. (OP source is not using jquery or added that tag)

Comment: Sure, but in terms of keeping code clean, wouldn't using less actual written code be a better solution. I'd assume OP would be using jQuery at some point. It's fair to comment, though, I feel the downvotes unnecessary. OP's way just seems harder and messier than it could be. Alas, OP's choice. Thanks for explaining.

Comment: The CSS for the menu is in the style sheet as display: none;

Comment: Just a note for future reference, [Unless a tag for a framework or library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected for questions with the javascript tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info). That is the most likely cause of the downvotes. Unfortunately, I cannot upvote because this question does not ask for nor does it include the tag for jQuery. The same goes for [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31234297/4639281).